# SmartGWT - ¿Cómo comprobar si un ListGridRecord está expandido o contraido?

Tags: java, smartgwt

Tengo un custom ListGrid en el cual los records pueden ser expandidos. Sé que existe una pequeña flecha verde para expandir o contraer estos elementos en la parte de arriba/izquierda de la fila, pero no sé si es posible comprobar programáticamente el estado de la fila seleccionada.

Mi código de ejemplo:

```
private RecordClickHandler gatherRecordClickHandler() {

    return new RecordClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onRecordClick(RecordClickEvent event) {
            //Aquí es donde quiero hacer la comprobación
            if(/*comprobacion*/)
                collapseRecord(event.getRecord());
            else
                expandRecord(event.getRecord());
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se hace así:

```
if(myListGrid.isExpanded(event.getRecord))
    collapseRecord(event.getRecord());
else
    expandRecord(event.getRecord());
```